# Creating dynamic Master-Details view on one page using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, architecture

This is a design / technology question.

Using ASP.NET MVC I can easily create a simple application with two views one, master view showing all records in tabular form read-only. And another one details view to create a new record.

My goal is to have the details form on the same page as the table.
The user enters data press save and a new records is added to the table **without switching the view and reloading content**. It should basically work like posting a new answer or comment in stackowerflow.

I found the way doing that by writing own jQuery code and communicating with controller actions using JSON. Is that the way these kind of dynamic forms are created in ASP.NET MVC?

With this approach I face following design/extensibility problem:

- Rendering the new row using jQuery seems to me a bit cluttered.
- I have two places to adjust if you add a new field - once in master view, second in jQuery script.

Currently I am adding the new record to table like this:

```
function addQueryField() {
      // Determine the index of the next row to insert
      var index = $("tr[id^=queryRow]").size();
      // Create DOM element for table row
      var oTr = $(document.createElement("tr")).attr("id", "queryRow" + index);
      // Create DOM element for value textbox
      var oValueTextBox = $(document.createElement("input")).attr("name", "query[" + index + "].Value").attr("id", "Value"+index).attr("type", "text"); 
    });
```

I am using basically the technique described [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jacqueseloff/archive/2009/04/17/creating-dynamic-forms-with-mvc-and-jquery.aspx).

Are there probably some out of the box solutions out there?

Comment: You are doing it right. Are you facing any problems with it ?

Comment: @Shyju
It is not a technical, but more the design/extensibility problem: 
1. Rendering the new row using jQury seems to me a bit cluttered.
2. In this case you have two places to adjust if you add a new field - once in master view, second in jQuery script.

Comment: what you want to add in jQuery script ? Can you please be more elaborative ?

Answer (score 1):

If i were you **I'll separate the adding process from updating the table "or part of page"**

I'm doing it like this:

1. Client clicked on Add button
2. I load the suitable `Create` partial view via jQuery and display it maybe in a Modal Window
3. Client fill the form and click Save
4. On save i validate the form first and if everything is OK i submit it via jQuery and prevent the page submitting
5. On the Controller i do what the `Post` require to to and if there are any `ModelState` Errors then i returned them as `JSON` to let the client side java-script code show these errors to the client
6. **If there are no errors returned from the server** then i update the partial part of the page "Or your table" via jQuery by **calling the server again** and let the `Controller` `Action` return partial view instead of full page view.

I know there are many things needs more explanation but i hope the idea is clear

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. The idea is clear.
So as I understand every add will cause the partial view with list of all items to reload. Sometimes it might be important to avoid that (for instance chat or forum application with many hundred records and high add rate). That's why I was adding the record form jQuery. But thank you anyway. If no one will come up with magic solution I will accept yours.

Comment: @achitaka-san You're welcomed :) And you're very right if you've such special situation but i'm talking in general. Anyway you could just change the behavior in the last step but you should check for the server ModelState before inserting the new item to the "PartialView"